# Angular/NGXS, Trouble testing an action based on failed API request

Tags: angular, rxjs, jasmine, ngxs

I'm having trouble trying to write tests for an NGXS action calling a http request. I would like to add some tests in case the request succeed or failed.

My Action:

```
    @Action(SearchChuckNorrisJokes)
    searchChuckNorrisJokes({ getState, setState }: StateContext<ChuckNorrisStateModel>, { searchString }: SearchChuckNorrisJokes) {
        // Handle loading
        const state = getState();
        return this.chuckNorrisService.fetchCustomChuckNorrisJokes(searchString).subscribe(
            res => {
                setState({
                    ...state,
                    loading: false,
                    error: false,
                    chuckData: res['result'],
                });
            }, err => {
                setState({
                    ...state,
                    loading: false,
                    error: true,
                });
                return throwError(err);
            }
        );
```

Spec:

```
describe('ChuckStateComponent', () => {
    let store: Store;
    let chuckState: ChuckNorrisState;
    let apiService: ApiService;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [NgxsModule.forRoot([ChuckNorrisState]), HttpClientTestingModule, HttpClientTestingModule],
            providers: [ApiService]
        }).compileComponents();
        store = TestBed.get(Store);
        chuckState = TestBed.get(ChuckNorrisState);
        apiService = TestBed.get(ApiService);
    }));

    it('should toggle a failed API call', () => {
        spyOn(chuckState, 'searchChuckNorrisJokes').and.returnValue(throwError({ 'An Error' })); 
        spyOn(apiService, 'fetchCustomChuckNorrisJokes').and.returnValue(throwError({ 'status: 404' }));
        store.dispatch(new SearchChuckNorrisJokes(null));
        store.selectOnce(state => state.chuckData).subscribe(data => {
            expect(data.error).toBe(true); // Never set to false
        });
    });
});
```

I believe that I am spying on the state/service but since I am using the NGXS store, it does not see that my I have mocked a response.

I am happy to provide more information if needed. Been battling this for the last day or so, and surprised there is not more info for testing NGXS failed API calls...

Comment: What is `throwError` in your test? What does it return?

Comment: Your approach is invalid, you should never subscribe in action handlers. Also you return an instance of the `Subscription` class and NGXS doesn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Shadow.  Once you pipe your service call and return the observable your pattern of mocking the 'fetchCustomChuckNorrisJokes' should work for you.  I am not sure why you would need ChuckNorrisState in the spec at all either.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I needed to pipe out the response instead of subscribing to it. Many thanks.. Updated code incase anyone gets stuck:

State:

```
    @Action(SearchChuckNorrisJokes)
    searchChuckNorrisJokes({ getState, setState }: StateContext<ChuckNorrisStateModel>, { searchString }: SearchChuckNorrisJokes) {
        // Handle loading
        const state = getState();
        return this.chuckNorrisService.fetchCustomChuckNorrisJokes(searchString).pipe(
            tap(res => {
                setState({
                    ...state,
                    loading: false,
                    error: false,
                    chuckData: res['result'],
                });
            }),
            catchError(err => {
                setState({
                    ...state,
                    loading: false,
                    error: true,
                });
                return of(err);
            })
        );
    }
```

Spec:

```
    it('should toggle a failed API call', () => {
        spyOn(apiService, 'fetchCustomChuckNorrisJokes').and.returnValue(throwError({}));
        store.dispatch(new SearchChuckNorrisJokes(null));
        store.selectOnce(state => state.chuckData).subscribe(data => {
            expect(data.error).toBe(true);
        });
    });
```